# How to use gdb with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb, x86-64

I run a program with LD_PRELOADing a specific library. Like this.

```
LD_PRELOAD=./my.so ./my_program
```

How do I run this program with `gdb`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Do the following.

```
gdb your_program

(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD ./yourso.so
(gdb) start
```

Answer (score 22):

Posting because we ran into a case where `set environment` didn't work:

From [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html):

> ```
> set exec-wrapper wrapper
> show exec-wrapper
> unset exec-wrapper
> ```
>
> When ‘exec-wrapper’ is set, the specified wrapper is used to launch programs for debugging. gdb starts your program with a shell command of the form exec wrapper program. Quoting is added to program and its arguments, but not to wrapper, so you should add quotes if appropriate for your shell. The wrapper runs until it executes your program, and then gdb takes control.
>
> You can use any program that eventually calls execve with its arguments as a wrapper. Several standard Unix utilities do this, e.g. env and nohup. Any Unix shell script ending with exec "$@" will also work.
>
> **For example, you can use env to pass an environment variable to the debugged program, without setting the variable in your shell's environment**:
>
> ```
>          (gdb) set exec-wrapper env 'LD_PRELOAD=libtest.so'
>          (gdb) run
> ```

Answer (score 18):

A way to set both the environment and arguments in one command:

```
gdb --args env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libstderred.so /usr/bin/ls -l
```

This uses `env` to the same effect as an exec wrapper (like Alexey Romanov's answer), except that GDB doesn't know about it. The side effect is that your session will start in `env`. Fortunately, GDB will follow the exec into the target program as if nothing happened, and the backtrace is identical.

The convenience of having everything in one command is that your shell history will help you run the exact same thing again.

Comment: This is not using `env` as an exec wrapper in the sense that GDB talks about an exec-wrapper.  In this case you will start by debugging `env` itself.  When `env` does an `exec` to run `ls` GDB will follow the exec, but commands like `start` will not do what you expect - they will run to the start of `env`, not the start of `ls`, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 10):

You can supply `env` as an exec-wrapper on the command line using the `-iex` flag:

```
gdb -iex "set exec-wrapper env LD_PRELOAD=./my.so" ./my_program
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using gdbserver with VS Code, the simplest way is launching your program wrapped in a shell:

```
gdbserver :8888 sh -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/libtest.so your_prog'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can basically do it the same way, just add `gdb` before the program name:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./my.so gdb ./my.program
```

You can check the environment variables using:

```
(gdb) show environment LD_PRELOAD
```

In the rare case you actually need to change it inside gdb, e.g. when debugging a `dlopen()`, you ca do that:

```
(gdb) set environment LD_PRELOAD ./my.so
```

Oh, wait, it doesn't work for me with gdb 7.6.2! The library doesn't get loaded, that means none of the answer here are entirely correct, at least with current tools.

Comment: I'm guessing that the effect of the preload is unwanted for GDB itself (perhaps it's a mocking library that modifies `open()` and the like - such as `fakeroot` etc).