# How can I test my own implementation of GLIBC in NASM x64?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, libc

I'm currently developing my NASM x64 version of GLIBC, and I'm having a problem testing it. The ASM code is first compiled in .so, next my test code (in C language) is compiled via GCC, then I load my shared library via `LD_PRELOAD` and execute my binary.

Here's my ASM implementation of `putchar()` :

```
bits 64

STDOUT equ 1

section .text
    global putchar
    putchar:
        push rdi
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, STDOUT
        mov rsi, rsp
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall
        pop rdi
        ret
```

Here's the test main:

```c
#include <stddef.h>

extern size_t putchar(const char str);

int main(void)
{
    putchar('z');
    return (0);
}
```

And here's the Makefile :

```
CC      =   nasm
CFLAGS  =   -f elf64
SRC     =   $(wildcard src/*.asm)
OBJ     =   $(SRC:.asm=.o)
NAME    =   minilibc.so

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    ld -fPIC -shared -o $(NAME) $(OBJ) -nostdlib

%.o: %.asm
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

test: re
    gcc -o test/test test/main.c -g3
    LD_PRELOAD=./minilibc.so ./test/test

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

The problem is that GDB continues to use the glibc function when I try to set a breakpoint:

```bash
(gdb) b putchar
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1030
...
Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7c7bb20 in putchar () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

I've also tried compiling with `-nostlib` (in make test) but it doesn't work:

```bash
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001020
...
/home/mimahk/Documents/Workspace C/minilibc/test/main.c:7:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `putchar'
```

I know that in reality the binary needs a `_start` label to run but despite several searches I can't code it.

I tested this but it doesn't work:

```c
asm(".global _start; _start: call main; movq %rax, %rdi; movq $60, %rax;");
```

I get : `main.c:9:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to putchar`

Can you tell me how I can test my shared library?

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382589/smallest-executable-program-x86-64 ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: I don't see how that's even related, unless you mean the OP should write their own `_start` by hand in asm and call C's `main` from that?  In which case [How to get arguments value in \_start and call main() using inline assembly in C, without Glibc or CRT start files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855) is a better link.  Or call their asm functions by hand?  (Which might hide the fact that putchar takes a char by value, not a pointer that could be passed to `write`.)

Comment: Of course, yes, they could test their code by linking it normally into an executable, perhaps with different function names so they can test a few functions without writing a complete libc.

Comment: When you built with `-nostdlib`, did you link with your shared library that defines `putchar`?  Like `gcc main.c -nostdlib -lminilibc`?  Maybe with `-L.` or something to add it to the linker search path?  If not, of course it didn't find a definition for `putchar` because you didn't give it any at link time.

Comment: I'd highly recommend debugging your example functions so that's not a distraction in questions about linking and shared libraries. It's straightforward to call a function like `my_putchar()` from C if you link that `.o` directly into the executable, like `gcc main.c putchar.o`.  I think it'll even take precedence over the shared library name if you call it `putchar`.  Once you have your functions at least somewhat tested and working, then you can worry about putting them in a shared library and calling them there.  See also [a working Linux `putchar`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077).

Comment: @VirgilG.: Yes, `LD_PRELOAD` can interpose new symbol definitions **for an already successfully-linked executable**, that get used instead of the definitions in the shared libraries it's linked against (which had to exist for it to get linked correctly in the first place).  It can't provide the *only* definition of a symbol; running the program is a separate command that can't happen until after the linker is finished making an executable.  Linking needs to see that all the symbols are resolved out of the inputs you give it.

Comment: Oh right, `-nostdlib` omits the CRT startup files, so you'd need to provide your own minimal `_start`, e.g. like Matteo's answer in [How to get arguments value in \_start and call main() using inline assembly in C, without Glibc or CRT start files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50260855) (or my ultra-hacky one that avoids inline asm).  You actually *couldn't* link in glibc's CRT startup files (like `/lib/crtn.o` or wherever your distro puts them), since they depend on calling `__libc_start_main` in libc, which your mini libc presumably doesn't have.

Comment: Works fine here with the `LD_PRELOAD`: `Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7bd81f0 in putchar () from ./minilibc.so`

Comment: Or you could just link normally and use LD_PRELOAD and single-step into the functions if GDB gets confused about which symbol to set breakpoints on.  (perhaps with `gcc -fno-plt` so single-stepping into the first call doesn't go into the lazy dynamic linker).  Or for convenient debugging give your functions different names, like `mini_putchar`.  Also, you can't post buggy code an expect a crowd of helpful people not to say anything about it.  It's distracting, and a bad example for any future readers.

Comment: BTW the `mov rsi, [rsp-4]` is still wrong, that should be a `lea`. Or the whole thing can be simplified to `push rdi; mov rsi, rsp; ... ; pop rdi`.

Comment: Are you maybe using GDB incorrectly with LD_PRELOAD?  [How to use gdb with LD\_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10448254).  After doing `set environment LD_PRELOAD ./minilibc.so` and doing `start` to start the program, `b putchar` says it's setting a breakpoint at 2 locations.

Comment: The segfault is likely because with `-nostdlib` you have no code that calls `exit`. But gdb should tell you the location of the crash.

Comment: Of course GCC warns about that source; as it rightly says, you've prototyped `putchar` in a way that doesn't match the ISO C definition (and GCC's builtin definition) of `int putchar(int)`.  You might want to use `gcc -fno-builtin` for testing libc so it doesn't do stuff like optimize `printf` into `puts`, or optimizing away `memcpy`.  As for a segfault, presumably somewhere in code you're not showing, perhaps due to a `_start` that isn't expecting `main` to return, but yours does.  Use a debugger to find out where you segfault, and fix it.

Comment: Shared-library functions should have their type set to `function`, like `global putchar:function`.  I've read that libraries should also have sizes set for their symbols, and `ld` mentions that in its warning.  In GAS you'd do `.size putchar,  . - putchar` to have the assembler calculate a size.  (`.` in GAS is the same as `$` in NASM, so it's just setting the symbol's size metadata to `$ - begin`).   https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.5 that I linked in my answer to your previous question shows an example of the NASM syntax for that, also part of the `global` directive.

Comment: You are missing the `syscall` instruction from the end ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to comments from @PeterCordes and @Jester I was able to correct the problem.

First, I had to modify the code to precede `main()` with an ASM label named `_start`.

Then I modified a few options in my Makefile to link the .so directly at runtime (and added the basic debug options):

`-ggdb3`: Enables in-depth debugging with GDB.

`-fno-builtin`: Removes GCC's automatic code replacements (e.g. `printf("%s\n", str)` by `puts(str)`.

`-nostdlib`: Do not include GLIBC.

`-fno-plt`: Use GOT directly without PLT.

`-L./ -lminilibc`: Instructs the linker to link my executable to the `minilibc` library (**it should therefore be called `libminilibc.so`**).

`-Wl,-rpath=./`: Tells the linker where my library is at runtime (because it's not in `/usr/lib/`) and saves me the trouble of using `LD_PRELOAD`.

Here's the complete code:

main.c

```c
extern int putchar(const char str);

asm(".global _start; _start: call main; movq %rax, %rdi; movq $60, %rax; syscall"); // Call the main() function and exit with the code corresponding to the return of main().

int main(void)
{
    putchar('H');
    return (0);
}
```

Makefile

```
CC      =   nasm
CFLAGS  =   -f elf64
SRC     =   $(wildcard src/*.asm)
OBJ     =   $(SRC:.asm=.o)
NAME    =   libminilibc.so

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    ld -shared -o $(NAME) $(OBJ)

%.o: %.asm
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

test: re
    gcc -o test/test test/main.c -ggdb3 -fno-builtin -nostdlib -fno-plt -L./ -lminilibc -Wl,-rpath=./

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

Comment: `-fnostdlib` isn't a GCC option.  You mean `-nostdlib`.

Comment: Also, in your `ld` command in your Makefile, `-nostdlib` and `-fPIC` isn't an `ld` option.  `-fPIC` is a GCC code-generation option; `ld` doesn't make code, it just links.  `ld -nostdlib` does exist, but means not to search standard paths for things you specify with `-l`.    Bare `ld` doesn't link anything you didn't tell it to, so this isn't making it not link stuff, it's just setting search paths.   (If it wasn't an option at all, it would get parsed as `ld -n -o stdlib`, setting `--nmagic` and the output file name.  Don't pass random stuff to `ld`!  e.g. `-fPIC` is `--auxiliary=PIC`)